# Create new nested dictionary using nested key, values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of key-value pairs, where the value is itself a dictionary. I would like to change the names of key values in that nested dictionary based on a predefined conversion.

I am using two lists to match up the values of the nested keys that I am trying to conver (`Old_item1` should become `New_item1`):

```
comparison_list = ['Old_item1', 'Old_item2']
new_prods = ['New_item1', 'New_item2']

old_dict = {
    'Company1':
        {
            'Old_item1':
                {
                    'key1': val,
                    'key2': val
                },
            'Old_item2':
                {
                    'key1': val,
                    'key2': val
                }
        }
}
```

I tried this:

```
new_dict = {}
for i in comparison_list:
    for j in new_prods:
        new_dict['Company1'][j] = test['Company1'][i]
```

I get a KeyError: `KeyError: 'Company1'`

The desired output for each item I add to each list is:

```
new_dict = {
    'Company1':
        {
            'New_item1':
                {
                    'key1': val  # old item key, val
                    'key2': val  # old item key, val
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: You will probably want as an intermediate step to set up a dictionary that maps the old keys to the new keys (use `zip` on the two lists to iterate when constructing this).

Comment: Nathaniel Ford's edit makes me sound much smarter than I am

Comment: @chasedcribbet Nonsense! You're plenty smart - I hope the edit helps teach the widely used language for this sort of thing, but I also want to be sure you don't feel the need to apologize for asking a question or being new to this particular area of knowledge. That's why we're all here!

Comment: @NathanielFord No worries. Just trying to get a laugh

Comment: @OlavAga made a good point below. The question now looks like I wanted to change the names, but what I wanted is a new, separate dict.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a dictionary of mappings from the old to the new items, and then use it to create a new sub-dictionary for each company.  This then needs to be wrapped inside an outer loop over companies (although here there is only one).

For example:

```
comparison_list = ['Old_item1', 'Old_item2']
new_prods = ['New_item1', 'New_item2']
    
old_dict = {'Company1': 
            {'Old_item1': 
             {'key1': 2, 
              'key2': 3},
             'Old_item2': 
             {'key1': 4,
              'key2': 5}}} 

key_mappings = dict(zip(comparison_list, new_prods))

new_dict = {k: {key_mappings[k1]: v1 for k1, v1 in v.items()}
            for k, v in old_dict.items()}

print(new_dict)
```

gives:

```
{'Company1': {'New_item1': {'key1': 2, 'key2': 3}, 'New_item2': {'key1': 4, 'key2': 5}}}
```

Here is the mappings dictionary `key_mappings` which we used:

```
{'Old_item1': 'New_item1', 'Old_item2': 'New_item2'}
```

Comment: Be aware with this solution that it will not handle any keys in the old_dict that are not also in the key_mapping and give you a `KeyError`.

Comment: @NathanielFord Yes, that is correct. I was assuming that all the keys will be in those lists.

Comment: @NathanielFord If the keys are not present, then I guess there are different options depending on the requirements. It might be that the original key should be used - in which case a `get` as you suggest (here: `key_mappings.get(k1, k1)` in place of `key_mappings[k1]`) will do the job nicely. Or it might be that it should be omitted entirely, in which case an `if k1 in key_mappings` inside the inner dict comprehension could be used.

Comment: I agree! It's not specified in the OP, and there are different dynamics depending on which way you want to go. - which you've described quite well. :)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to go about this is to re-create your dictionary with a comprehension:

```
new_dict = {company: update_item(v) for company, v in old_dict.items()}
```

Then parse out `update_item` to it's own function. You *could* do this inline but it makes it difficult to understand.

```
conversion_lookup = {
    'Old_item1': 'NewItem1',
    'Old_item2': 'NewItem2',
}

def update_item(item: dict) -> dict:
    return { conversion_lookup.get(k, k): v for k, v in item.items() }

new_dict = {company: update_item(v) for company, v in old_dict.items()}
```

For the conversion here I'm using a dictionary describing the conversion. If you need to construct this automatedly:

```
comparison_list = ['Old_item1', 'Old_item2']
new_prods = ['New_item1', 'New_item2']

conversion_lookup = { v: new_prods[idx] for idx, v in enumerate(comparison_list) }
```

The reason I like a dictionary is that you can use `some_dict.get(a_value, a_default_value)`. Then, if your value isn't in your conversion dictionary you can fall back to the original value. That's what I'm doing here:

```
conversion_lookup.get(k, k)
```

The second `k` is the original item's value, which is a good thing to use if your conversion list doesn't include what you want.

Comment: With your `for company, v in old_dict`, do you mean `for company, v in old_dict.items()`? If you iterate over a dictionary, you will just get the keys.

Comment: Yup! I do. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to do it step by step. First create the dicts with the new names and old keys, then remove the old keys, and finally add in the new names.

```py
# Keep the values from the old keys
values = [old_dict['Company1'][old_name] for old_name in comparison_list]

# Remove old names, and add in the 
for new_key, value, old in zip(new_prods, values, comparison_list):
    old_dict['Company1'].pop(old)
    old_dict['Company1'][new_key] = value
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's being accomplished with the `pop`?  They should simply be overwritten when you do the update, right?

Comment: The keys are different, for instance "New_item1" will not overwrite "Old_item1". Without pop, both keys would exist after the update

Comment: I think you might be off by one with regards to nesting level. Running your code puts `new_item1`, etc. on the same level as `Company1` - which is not what you want. I think this is an awkward approach for that reason.

Comment: True, nice catch. Also unsure whether it should mutate the original dict or create a new one. Statement in the question points towards mutation, but attempted solution transforms it into a new dict

Comment: To correct @NathanielFord's last point (subject to the existing limitation of the single hard-coded top-level key) just change `old_dict.update` to `old_dict['Company1'].update`

Comment: Generally in Python I find it as or more efficient to create a new dict and just replace the previous one - the way the underlying dynamics work it's basically the same thing and way easier to reason about. Also, alani is correct about the fix for the update issue, though you'd have to do it for each company and you'd have to put the whole thing in a loop or something similar to make that work.

Comment: My original question pointed to a new_dict. I think it may have been lost in the edits.